# How to capture in a variable the errors of some python code executed by 'exec'?

Tags: python, exec

first of all sorry for my english, I'm Spaniard ;-)

I'm making and script that receives some Python code and captures the output and the errors that that code would contain; this is the code I have:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer_err = StringIO()
buffer_out = StringIO()

sys.stderr = buffer_err
sys.stdout = buffer_out

exec '''SOME PYTHON CODE'''

sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

print buffer_err.getvalue()
print buffer_out.getvalue()
```

This code works great capturing the output of Python code that doesn't contain any errors.

But the problem comes when the code contains one or more errors, then I don't know why, the `exec` doesn't ends and all the code that follows its never executed.

Thanks for your attention, cheers.

Comment: Use `try`/`except` around the `exec` statement.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but then the `exec` directly isn't executed and I need to execute it and to get its output or its errors.

Comment: You'd need to print the error message yourself (out just append it to the error buffer directly). Maybe something in the traceback module will help.

Comment: Okay thanks, at end the `try`/`except` solution worked, but I can't know what kind of error does the `exec` statement contain... For now this solution is OK, maybe later I will neet to improve it. Thanks.